# How can I register a call-back on suspend in a linux driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a linux driver and I would like to register a callback function to be invoked when  the system goes to sleep.  What is the api to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of the kernel are you working with?

Comment: I'm working with kernel 2.6 and greater.

Comment: Is this a chardev, PCI device ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I settled on was using notifier chains.  On later versions of the kernel you can register with [register_pm_notifier](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/power/main.c#L28).  If your kernel doesn't support that api you can use the notifier for [cpu hot-plug events](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/cpu.c#L127) (this appears to be what KVM uses). On the way in and out of suspend the cpu hotplug notifier chain fires.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of driver you have.  For example, if you have a driver that is registered with `platform_device_register()`, then the `struct platform_driver` includes a `.suspend` member for the device's suspend callback.  With PCI devices, the `struct pci_driver` that you pass to `pci_register_driver()` similarly includes a `.suspend` member.

Most device classes should provide a similar mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want `acpi_install_fixed_event_handler()`, found in `acpi/acpi.h` , the generic events found in `acpi/actypes.h` (which is included from `acpi.h`).

The second argument to `acpi_install_fixed_event()` wants a handler of type `u32`, with the last argument being a `void *context`. What I could not find is a list of possibilities that *context might be. However, it looks like you just something to be entered on events, which means you probably don't care about the context. Not *quite* a callback, but the same result.

If you register a fixed handler for (say, `ACPI_EVENT_POWER_BUTTON` or `ACPI_EVENT_SLEEP_BUTTON`), your handler should be entered on the respective event. I'm not 100% sure `ACPI_EVENT_SLEEP_BUTTON` is what you want, i.e. I can't quite tell if its the same event as the system going to sleep on its own. Testing and further investigation is, of course, and exercise for the reader.

An example of using it can be found in `drivers/rtc/rtc-cmos.c`.

Please take care to wrap any code from acpi.h in

```
#ifdef  CONFIG_ACPI
 ....

#endif /* CONFIG_ACPI */
```

I could be completely wrong here, I have not actually needed to do this for any of the drivers that I've written. The above is the result of about 30 minutes of digging through the source of **2.6.32.8** , which may be completely different than the kernel you are working with.

Please leave a comment if I am way off base :) I *think* this is what you are looking for.

**Additional**

As for licensing, its exported:

```
drivers/acpi/acpica/evxface.c:ACPI_EXPORT_SYMBOL(acpi_install_fixed_event_handler)
```

Not

```
*_EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL()
```

... So you should have no issues using it, whatever you happen to be doing.

Finally, this is a perfectly good question that would *probably* be met with a good reception on the Linux Kernel mailing list. If in doubt, ask there. Even if this 'just works', its a good idea to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. Unfortunately, testing reveals that this callback is only invoked on actual button press.

Comment: @lucas - what kind of device is it? Chardev, PCI, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

The [ACPI Howto](http://www.columbia.edu/~ariel/acpi/acpi_howto.txt) probably will give you a good headstart...

Comment: Not very helpful. He's looking for an exported FP symbol he can use in his module so its notified of specific events. That's actually a very good question, especially for modules that might be unwittingly using the BKL for ioctl.